# How do I retrieve data from a textbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

Very new to JavaScript/HTML, help!

I have 2 text boxes and a submit button. I am trying to retrieve the data from each of them using JavaScript and for the time being, simply put them into an alert box.

However, on clicking the button, the alert just reads 'undefined', help!

Here's a code snippet:

```js
function submitApp() {
  var authValue = document.getElementsByName("appAuthor").value;
  var titleValue = document.getElementsByName("appTitle").value;

  alert(authValue);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="appAuthor" size="" maxlength="30" />
<input type="text" name="appTitle" maxlength="30" />

<input type="button" value="Submit my Application!" onclick="submitApp()" />
```

Comment: ``document.getElementsByName("appAuthor")[0].value`` and
``document.getElementsByName("appTitle")[0].value``

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a list of elements, even if there is only one by that name. You'll need to iterate the results.

Comment: @ElGuapo you're thinking of `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: This is why most of us would use getElementById instead. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByName()` returns a list.  So you can grab the first item in the list:

```
document.getElementsByName("appAuthor")[0].value
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Worked straight away!

Answer (score 1):

[`.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) method returns an array-like node *list*, so you'll need to specify an index in order to retrieve a specific input's value (because the `value` property only applies to DOM elements, not an entire list).

```
function submitApp() {
    var authValue = document.getElementsByName("appAuthor")[0].value;
    var titleValue = document.getElementsByName("appTitle")[0].value;
    alert(authValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use getElementsByName or getElementsByClassName, it returns array of elements, so you should put index to access each element.

```
authValue = document.getElementsByName("appAuthor")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this jQuery to a document.ready section like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        submitApp();
    });

    function submitApp() {
        var authValue = document.getElementsByName("appAuthor")[0].value;
        var titleValue = document.getElementsByName("appTitle")[0].value;

        alert(authValue);
   }
});

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit my Application!">
```

If you want to submit the form remove the e.preventDefault();, but if you just want the value updated keep it in there to prevent form submition.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially change the button type into a submit-type and do something like this:

```
$('body').find('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var authValue = $('input[name="appAuthor"]').val();
    var titleValue = $('input[name="appTitle"]').val();
    //...here do whatever you like with that information
    //Below empty the input
    $('input').val('');
})
```

Or just interpret the form as an array to make your life easier and clean the code up.